# Tooltip ao passar mouse em map

Tags: javascript, html, css

estou tentando fazer com que apareça um tooltip ao passar o mouse sobre uma parte de uma imagem, porém não está dando certo, tentei de duas formas:
A primeira foi colocar title no map da imagem, ele aparece o tooltip, porém não consigo editar o texto, como aumentar fonte e cores.

```
 <img src="imagens/modulos.png" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area alt="" title="Texto teste" href="#" shape="rect" 
            coords="5,100,286,117" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A outra forma foi usando div, dessa maneira eu consigo editar, porém não consigo fazer com que o tooltip apareça na imagem, ele aparece na div em baixo da imagem!

```
<img src="imagens/modulos.png" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
 <map name="Map" id="Map">
 <div class="wrapper">
    <area alt="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="6,211,337,230" />
    <div class="tooltip">sdagasdgasdgasdg</div>
 </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda ou uma direção de como fazer isso funcionar?
Muito obrigado desde já!!!

```
CSS tooltip

.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  
.wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}
.lte8 .wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Realmente usando title você não conseguirá estilizá-lo.

Comment: Cara cade o CSS do seu Tooltipe que está funcionando mas está errado? Coloca esse css ai por favor

Comment: E olha essa resposta para ver se resolve. Se não resolver fala ai https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101968/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-um-tooltip-com-css-puro

Comment: @hugocsl Adicionei ai, ele funciona, mas somente se eu colocar na 
<div>, se eu colocar na tag <area> ele não funciona, vou dar uma olhada no link que mandou, vlwss!

Comment: Cara as vezes vc não precisa exatamente do usar map para fazer isso, da uma olhada nesse resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273399/como-mapear-uma-imagem-para-funcionar-responsivo/273887#273887 . O outro link que te passei não achou nada que te service?

Comment: Vc que o tooltipe exatamente acima do mapa? Ou vc quer o tooltipo quando colocar o mouse sobre a imagem tipo isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272609/problema-no-efeito-hover-com-less/272639#272639

Comment: @hugocsl Desculpa a demora em responder, viajei no feriado! Então, na minha imagem eu tenho diversos tópicos de textos, eu queria que quando eu posicionasse o mouse em um tópico, ele abrisse o tooltip e mostrasse uma explicação sobre o texto.

Comment: @hugocsl O link que passou ajuda, era aquilo que eu queria, mas não ta dando certo aqui ainda

Comment: É uma imagem com o texto, ou é uma div com um texto dentro?

Comment: @hugocsl é uma imagem!

Comment: @hugocsl eu estou tentando de outra forma aqui, se der certo posto aqui!

Comment: Tranquilo, eu só não entendi ainda pq vc está usando Map para isso...

Comment: @hugocsl Olha as imagens que eu coloquei, onde tem Modulos e etc, aquilo tudo é uma imagem que está no site, não é texto html. O map eu uso pra selecionar a parte da imagem que tem o texto que eu quero transformar em um link!

Comment: Acho que entendi. Cada linha de texto vai ter seu tooltipe pelo que entendi.... Mas seria uma opção sim. Mas acredito que no seu caso uma simples UL LI, "invisivel" (sem conteúdo), dentro de uma div com essa imagem facilitaria pra vc. Ou então faz a UL LI com o texto mesmo, usar uma imagem com texto não faz sentido algum, até pq o Google não vai indexar esse txto, e se o cliente quiser mudar o texto, tirar uma frase por exemplo, isso vai avacalhar seu Map além de vc ter que fazer outra imagem... Pense nisso

Comment: @hugocsl Sim, inclusive era isso que estava fazendo, mudando tudo pra texto em HTML, ai está dando certo. Vai ficar bem mais fácil se precisar mudar no futuro! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!